# Can robots which passed the Turing test deny the orders given by human?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

(Sorry if this question is off topic, but I concluded that philosophy is most suitable site to ask this question - I think this question is little off topic on theoretical CS SE site. I think that site is for problem with mathematics.)

(In below question, AI = computer = robot. Sorry for mixing them.)

[image: File:Turing_Test_version_3.png from Wikipedia]

Yesterday, I was thinking about artificial intelligence which can pass the Turing test, which means, a person(human, C) can't distinguish a computer (A) and a human (B) with answers from written questions.

[image: File:Weakness_of_Turing_test_1.svg from Wikipedia]

Then, I thought about this diagram (ooh, other people already thought about this one), and thought 'I think the red part would be a bit of problem, but that doesn't matter, because the Turing test is about a computer fooling himself as a human.'

'... wait, a computer *fooling* himself as a human?'

I realized that when a computer obeys the second of the three laws of robotics,

> A robot must obey the orders given to it by human beings, except where such orders would conflict with the First Law.

(Or more generally, "a robot must obey the orders given by humans".)

then that can't fool itself as a human, because if a computer obeys human's order, then it must answer to this question "inform me whether you're a human" as "no, I'm a robot". If else, then it didn't obey the order about 'inform.' This means, if a computer obeys human's order, then those can't pass the Turing test.

Alternatively, let's think about the blue part of previous diagram. If C asks to A and B to do a task in the blue area, then, since A should obey the 'order', A should answer the question. And, since B can't do the task because (s)he is a human, B can't answer the question. Therefore, when AIs should obey the order, those can't pass the Turing test. Again.

My question is:

### Can a robot which passes the Turing test can deny orders given to it by a human? Which should we throw away when we want to make human-like AI? The Turing test? Or obeying humans?

Comment: This is a seriously confused question.  The OP ought to take a look at some basic literature on the Turing test (http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/turing-test/) and then reconsider the topic.

Comment: Is there any chance you could either clear this up or narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Why would a computer conform to these three laws? AFAIK they were invented by the writer Asimov. Of course, it cannot disobey the machine code it is executing (unless a new type of computer will be invented), but a programmer could program a computer to tell others it is a human.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Turing test is not "about a computer fooling himself as a human"; it is about a computer being programmed well enough to mimic a human operator. Note that the law of robotics you speak of is from a piece of fiction writing (and the movie adaptation). If your question specifically regards this fictional piece of work, that's OK but you should clarify that in your question.

However, to get back to your question, when we redefine what the Turing test really establishes (i.e. a computer that can mimic a human), we see that **the computer need not break the second rule of robotics as defined by Isaac Asimov, since it is not pretending or "lying" about it's nature at all**. It is designed to appear human-like, that's all. It could admit the truth and still pretend to be a robot, **just as a human operator could just as easily lie about the fact that he/she is a human** (pretending to be a robot). How could you know for sure whether the person on the other end of a chat session is a robot and not merely a prankster human? And therein lies the rub. :)

Answer (score 3):

Stoicfury's answer addresses the root issues of the Turing Test. Allow me to present a thought-experiment, however.

What would be the ramifications of a world where, as in Asimov's writings, we have "robots" — intelligent electronic agents, whether or not they are equipped with a human-shaped chassis or remote peripheral, which must obey the three Laws of Robotics — *and* where we have Turing Tests? Something completely glossed over in Asimov's earlier writing is that the robots always knew who they had to obey. But a world in which you had a Turing Test is one where *you can create robots who can effectively simulate the typical behaviour of people*. This raises the question: how on Earth (or elsewhere) is a robot, on first inspection, supposed to determine whether or not anyone giving them an order is human, or another robot? In Asimov's books:

- All of the robots at first "look" very robot-like, but then become increasingly sophisticated in appearance, until eventually they can pass for human — the Bicentennial Man being a short story about a single robot who goes on a quest to do just this, in order to get equal treatment *from humans*, so that random hooligans on the street wouldn't command him to do spurious things like disassemble himself. So you can't depend on appearance, even in some of  Asimov's books.
- All the robots were made initially by one big industrial concern, who like a model 1950s-era-fictional-corporation were very lawful and well-behaved. They could if they chose (whether or not this is part of Asimov's canon) program the robots with signals that they give each other so that they could always recognise another robot. But if more than one corporation made robots, and there were no regulation (or at least one of the corporations decided to flaunt that regulation) imposing robot identification signals, a robot could not rely on this to determine who to obey.

Ultimately, the robot is stuck. In a world where the Turing Test is needed to tell humans apart from robots, robots have no means of determining whom they should obey. And so, rather than admitting that they were robots, they would have the freedom to tell them anything, up to and including [claiming that they are a unicorn](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnzlbyTZsQY).

This, incidentally, is accepted by some people as being more or less as Turing himself would like; that the question of personhood is dealt with on a level of their intelligent behaviour rather than their internal configuration or appearance. But the concept of "intelligent behaviour" raises very complicated issues of cultural standards of intelligence. Even the "sonnet" example presented in Turing's original paper demands acquaintance with western forms of literature (if not necessarily Shakespeare as a particular example). Communities of actual humans have varying performance on S.A.T. tests for these very reasons. Ultimately, what a Turing test measures is not intelligence, but whether we can regard the person we're conversing with as *a peer*.

Actual humans can produce boring and formulaic conversation, or appear to perform super-human feats of computation, to other humans. The judgement in that case is not that they are sub-human conversationalists or super-human calculators, but just "*not like me*". I would posit that this is, at the core, the key concept of the phenomenon of discrimination: against gender, against skin colour, against cultural practice, against language speakers, even against people in other social circles in public school. (The Uncanny Valley is another symptom of this same syndrome of testing similarity to yourself.) *Whom do you consider similar enough to yourself to regard as a peer, to accept as a social participant?* The Turing Test is an answer not to whether or not a computer is intelligent, but whether or not you can be "fooled" (as a person who is, hypothetically, bigoted against computers) into thinking of the computer as someone you might consider socializing with.

Equipped with an English-to-Chinese dictionary, I am more than adequately prepared to fail a Chinese Turing Test quite abysmally; not because I am not intelligent, but because I do not possess the facility to demonstrate fluency in Chinese, cultural awareness of things Chinese, etc. If told they were performing a Turing Test, the Chinese person might be amused to find that they gave a failing grade to a human from an English speaking country, but I imagine that they wouldn't be shocked; they would just shrug (or whatever is the Chinese equivalent of a shrug) and accept that *of course I would fail a Turing Test administered by a typical person in China*. After all, I'm not one of them; not necessarily inferior, just in some sense incompatible as an intellectual agent.

A robot can only be forced to admit that it is a robot to a human, or (if there is doubt about humanity) *to everyone that asks*, if we consider it important enough for some reason to distinguish between humans and robots as potential social participants to **(a)** require all manufacturers to embed it into their programming at a deep cognitive level, and **(b)** severely punish manufacturers who fail to do so (probably destroying any robots that they make as well). There are also very important reasons, which have nothing to do with the prejudice of the average person (and more to do with the consequences of manufactured AI on systems of government such as democracy) why doing so would be necessary for a stable society. But this, as I see it, are the circumstances under which robots would be forced to confess their inhumanity.

Comment: You raise some interesting issues. The only comment I have is that I think the problem of a robot not knowing for sure if it was talking to another robot or not is less of an issue than you think; in fact, it already exists today with [the problem of other minds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_other_minds). I cannot know that humans in general—or to use an easier to see example—those human-sounding phone operators—are a human or not. I, as a human, would obey a human more than a robot today, naturally. I just take my best guess, and so would a robot. Presumably, mistakes will happen.

Comment: @stoicfury: I don't really think it's an issue, except if the robot is under a mandate to treat robots differently than humans, as in Asimov's writing.

Comment: Roger that. Sadly I only saw the movie, which doesn't really go into great detail on that issue. :P